# Colour text to match the colours in \inputminted

Tags: color, minted, syntax-highlighting

I use `\inputminted` to include snippets of C code in my document. These snippets are nicely coloured.

I know I can write e.g. `\textcolor{red}{foo}` but instead of `red` I want to say "the same colour which inputminted uses for a variable/type/macro/comment".

How can I colour text to match what `\inputminted` does?

Comment: just look in the _minted directory and see the generated latex for the file and use the same colours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{C}
if(!foo){
 for(zz=0;zz<-1;zz++) {
    a=b;
 }
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

If you look in the directory `_minted-`*jobname* then you will see the latex version of the file (or environment in this case) in a file with a very long unique name.

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PYG{k}{if}\PYG{p}{(}\PYG{o}{!}\PYG{n}{foo}\PYG{p}{)\PYGZob{}}
 \PYG{k}{for}\PYG{p}{(}\PYG{n}{zz}\PYG{o}{=}\PYG{l+m+mi}{0}\PYG{p}{;}\PYG{n}{zz}\PYG{o}{\PYGZlt{}\PYGZhy{}}\PYG{l+m+mi}{1}\PYG{p}{;}\PYG{n}{zz}\PYG{o}{++}\PYG{p}{)} \PYG{p}{\PYGZob{}}
    \PYG{n}{a}\PYG{o}{=}\PYG{n}{b}\PYG{p}{;}
 \PYG{p}{\PYGZcb{}}
\PYG{p}{\PYGZcb{}}
\end{Verbatim}
```

Looking at that you can see for eaxmple that keywords such as **if** are set with `\PYG{k}` and operators such as **=** are set with `\PYG{o}`.

In `default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle` in the same directory:

```
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@o\endcsname
   {\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
```

and

```
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@k\endcsname
   {\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
```

so the colours we need are `\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}` and `\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{C}
if(!foo){
 for(zz=0;zz<-1;zz++) {
    a=b;
 }
}
\end{minted}

roses are \textcolor{red}{red}, violets are \textcolor{blue}{blue},
keywords are \textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{keyword colour} and
operators are \textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{operator grey}.

\end{document}
```